# LINQ multiple Joins with a Group By

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

After trying a lot I decided to post a question here. My code is the following:

```
var query =
            //Customers
            from customer in context.Customers

            //Engineer 1
            join engineer1 in context.Employees on customer.PrimaryEngineer equals
            engineer1.EmployeeId into eng1 
            from engineer1 in eng1.DefaultIfEmpty()

            //Engineer Top
            join engineerTop in context.Employees on customer.TopEngineer equals 
            topEngineer.EmployeeId into top
            from engineerTop in top.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Then, what I want i group by attributes from the three tables : Customer, Employees (this one repeats for every engineer)

How can I group by attributes from the three tables?

The next code:

```
            group new {customer, engineer1, engineerTop} by new {customer.Name .....}
```

doesn't work due to engineer1 and engineerTop are from the same context?

I'm very confused with this.

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to assign a name to the anonymous type properties in the grouping due to multiple properties with the same name. (two times the EmployeeId?)

```
    var query = (
        //Customers
        from customer in context.Customers

        //Engineer 1
        join engineer1 in context.Employees on customer.PrimaryEngineer equals
        engineer1.EmployeeId into eng1 
        from engineer1 in eng1.DefaultIfEmpty()

        //Engineer Top
        join engineerTop in context.Employees on customer.TopEngineer equals 
        engineerTop.EmployeeId into top
        from engineerTop in top.DefaultIfEmpty()
        group new {customer, engineer1, engineerTop} by new {CustName = customer.Name, EmpId1 = engineer1.EmployeeId, EmpId2 = engineerTop.EmployeeId} into grp
        select new
        {
            Name = grp.Key.CustName,
            EmpId1 = grp.Key.EmpId1,
            EmpId2 = grp.Key.EmpId2
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to give you a point on your answer but I can't as I don't have the enough reputation yet. About: (two times the EmployeeId?) -> Yes, I'm working with an already created database that has a lot of bugs and is very bad relational oriented...even has no foreign keys lol. Thanks again for you answer and sorry for my late reply.